# Redirect page inside web method c#

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, get, webmethod

Here I am using jquery ajax call. Ajax call hit an aspx page which is works fine. but I wants to redirect to another page inside the web method. I am using:

```
Respnse.Redirect("test.aspx"),Server.Transfer("test.aspx"), System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute("test.aspx", false);
HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("test.aspx");
```

but NO USE.

Answer (score 0):

you can not redirect in page in web api, you can redirect page when ajax call ends or redirect page where response function in ajax call;

```
window.location = 'YorUrl';
```

Answer (score 0):

Absoutly correct you need to redirect using either jquery or Javascript after ajax hit
like
window.location="test.aspx";